# Angular upgrade with Module Federation - "Collection does not have a schematics map."

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation

I'm upgrading a set of Angular applications from v12 to v16, and they use Module Federation and the Angular Architects' [module federation plugin](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/README.md).

After upgrading each app's Angular version successfully, and going one version at a time, I run the update command for the module federation plug-in. (Eg `ng update @angular-architects/module-federation@15`)

I get this

```
An unhandled exception occurred: 
Collection "[app dir location]node_modules/@angular-architects/module-federation/migrations.json" 
does not have a schematics map.
See "/private/var/folders/m_/s6hjt4t90170wpj43zq_g_q80000gr/T/ng-yftav3/angular-errors.log" 
for further details.
```

What is this schematics map of which they speak?

I've tried updating `@angular-eslint/schematics` and `@schematics/angular` but they don't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the module-federation library, not Angular. Have you posted an issue in that library's GitHub?

Comment: Did you try to update @angular-architects/module-federation manually ?I would recommend performing the upgrade manually using npm i @angular-architects/module-federation@15 instead of using ng update. If npm indicates that there are incompatible libraries, I would suggest upgrading those as well beforehand.

Comment: As I mention below, I did reach out directly in the library and received an answer from Manfred Steyer.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without your `package.json` info. You say that your angular successfully updated to v16, that means that you need "**@angular-architects/module-federation: ^16.0.0**". If everything else is relevant for Angular v16, the simplest solution for you might be uninstalling that pluggin and instaling its relevant version I mentioned above. If it doesn't help, you can do it manually in your package.json - just set version you want, run `npm install` (if any dependency problem appears you can solve it same way).

Answer (score 0):

"This can safely be ignored." At least that's what Manfred Steyer has replied on my question in the library repo.

https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/487#issuecomment-1973954145